# System.Drawing.Graphics.Transform has no effect in Mono under Ubuntu

Tags: graphics, mono, system.drawing

I have a very simple code that draws an image on a bitmap, the image must be drawn in the lower right corner. I use TranslateTransform to move the image. This works fine when run under Windows, however, TranslateTransform has no effect when run in Mono under Linux.

```
byte[] imageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"/home/alexey/Downloads/test.png");
using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(500, 500))
{
    using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        ImageAttributes attr = null;

        using (Image image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(imageBytes)))
        {
            GraphicsUnit srcGU = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
            RectangleF srcRect = image.GetBounds(ref srcGU);
            RectangleF bounds = new RectangleF(0, 0, 100, 100);

            // Destination points specify the bounding parallelogram.
            PointF[] dstPoints = new PointF[]
                { bounds.Location,
                  new PointF(bounds.X + bounds.Width, bounds.Y),
                  new PointF(bounds.X, bounds.Y + bounds.Height) };

            // Image must be in the in the lower right corner and it is if run the code under Windows.
            // But is run code under linux, the image is in the upper left corner.
            gr.TranslateTransform(400,400);

            gr.DrawImage(image, dstPoints, srcRect, srcGU, attr);
        }
    }
    bmp.Save(@"/home/alexey/Downloads/out.png", ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

Of course, the code is a simplified version of the real code that must work in both windows and Linux environments. I narrowed down the code and found that the problems under linux occur because Graphics.Transform has no effect in Mono under linux. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution would be to simply add 400 to the X and Y components of your dstPoints.

Comment: yes :) or simply transform dstPoints, but this won't work in all cases, for example for text rotation. So I need to make transformation work somehow.

Comment: Can anyone help me with above issue?